# How to detect scrolling if view is not changed in ScrollView in C#?

Tags: c#, scroll, uwp, scrollview

I am developing an UWP app with C#, I wrap an `Image` in a `ScrollView`, in the `Image` I show a page of doc, because the page size is smaller than screen, so if I scroll the screen, **view will not change**, but I still need to detect the scrolling event, I try to use `**ViewChanged**` or `**ViewChanging**` but they are not called, I think maybe it's beacuase of the view is not changed. Anyone know a solution to detect?

Below is part of my xaml file:

```
<ScrollViewer ViewChanging="ScrollViewChanged">          
    <Image Name="PageImage" SizeChanged="PageImage_SizeChanged"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It is not obvious what "scroll the screen" could mean.  Best to scroll the view.

Comment: It means scroll the wheel or use pen/finger scroll or use scrollbar to scroll

Comment: The "ViewChanging" event should be able to detect the scrolling, can you show us the code please?

Comment: Even if the view is not changed? Please see the code above, and I log an information in function ScrollViewChanged, but it is not printed when I scroll the wheel or drag the mouse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may get mouse wheel event. Hope the link will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_PointerWheelChanged

For touch/pen you may subscribe to these events:

```
              PointerPressed="ScrollViewer_PointerPressed"
              PointerMoved="ScrollViewer_PointerMoved"
              PointerExited="ScrollViewer_PointerExited"
              PointerReleased="ScrollViewer_PointerReleased"
```

And handle them in code behind like this:

```
    private bool _isPressed;

    private void ScrollViewer_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = true;
    }

    private void ScrollViewer_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            //your logic
        }
    }

    private void ScrollViewer_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = false;
    }

    private void ScrollViewer_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have found the function can detect mouse wheel, but I need to detect other input types like gesture or pen, so I need one whole function can detect all the input types scroll.

Comment: I've updated an answer hope it'll help you. From PointerMove event you may simulate scroll position.

Comment: Do you know how to get the movement of PointerMoved?